# NestJS handling UnhandledPromiseRejection with exception filters

Tags: node.js, nestjs

In NestJS the standard approach of handling errors is to let errors propagate up to the exception filter(s) so that code is not littered with try-catch blocks and exception logging and error conversion can be performed in one place.
With the move to node16, an event is thrown when there is no catch on a promise. This change seemingly leads to putting catch statements on all async calls. Is there a better approach that leverage the same exception filters methodology?

Comment: what about [catch evertying filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#catch-everything)?

Comment: We are using the catch everything filter, unfortunately it doesn't resolve this issue

Comment: I've been using node16 with no worries. Depending on the context of which the promise is being created, you don't need to handle it by yourself becase nestjs will catch it automatically. In this case, if you're getting the `UnhandledPromiseRejection`, I guess this could be due to floating promises.